# How to invoke lambda version based on versions provided as input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a use case where client sends a request with the following payload:

```
payload = {

identifier: arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account}:function:{function-name}:{version}
data = ""

}
```

I want to invoke lambdas based on identifier. There are some consideration:

- data in payload can very from Kbs to few MBs
- Lambda which need to be invoked can increase

I was thinking of having an api gateway which recieves request from the client which is then connected to a parent lambda A which invokes other child lambdas B and C based on identifier provided by the client. However I am not sure if the child lambda can handle few Mbs of data. Also is it a good way to chain lambdas in the following way

[image]

I was looking into how I can asynchronously invoke lambdas but I couldn't find anywhere where it allows to invoke lambdas based on versions. Any suggestions in this regard would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke another Lambda from Lambda based on version.

However, the problem with asynchronous invocation is that the payload size limit is less than what you need. According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), the size limit of invocation payload is 256 KB for asynchronous calls and 6 MB for synchronous calls.

I don’t know which language do you prefer, but invoking Lambda from another Lambda based on version with Python’s boto3 can look like this:

```py
import json
from boto3 import client as boto3_client

client = boto3_client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # ...
    client.invoke( 
        # your lambda identifier with version
        FunctionName=your_function_name,
        # to invoke a function asynchronously, set InvocationType to 'Event'
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(your_payload)
    )
    # ...
```

As stated by [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke), the 'FunctionName' parameter is the

> name of the Lambda function, *version*, or alias. […] You can append a
> version number or alias to any of the formats. The length constraint
> applies only to the full ARN. If you specify only the function name,
> it is limited to 64 characters in length.

The `invoke` function accepts the following name formats for 'FunctionName' argument:

```
Function name – my-function (name-only), my-function:v1 (with alias).
Function ARN – arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function.
Partial ARN – 123456789012:function:my-function.
```

> I can invoke but I have read that its an anti pattern also in my case
> lambda B and C will takes a long time to execute so Lambda A will wait
> for B or C to finish execution. ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/functions-calling-functions.html

Please note that this articles refers to synchronously calling Lambdas, which forces the functions to wait for a response. This is not the case with asynchronous invocation. When one Lambda invokes another asynchronously, AWS stores those events in an internal queue that it manages (so-called **Event Queue**). To invoke a function asynchronously, set the invocation type parameter to Event. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) for further information.

[image: sync-vs-async-Lambda-invocation]

Comment: yeah I can invoke but I have read that its an anti pattern also in my case lambda B and C will takes a long time to execute so Lambda A will wait for B or C to finish execution. 

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/functions-calling-functions.html